# Which is better checking of null types or using Any() in LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have this two codes and I have to know which is much better to use.
I'm thinking this is the same.
If I'm not mistaken, the first has only one call to the database, however,
I don't know if checking of the repo != null is right.

**(1)**

```
var repo = Repository
  .Query()
  .Where(ur => ur.CustomerId == customerId)
  .SingleOrDefault();

if (repo != null)
{
    // Update repo
    repo.Name = "name here";
}
else
{
    // code
}
```

**(2)**

```
var repo = Repository
  .Query()
  .Any(ur => ur.CustomerId == customerId);

if (repo)
{
    var result = Repository
      .Query()
      .Where(ur => ur.CustomerId == customerId)
      .Single();

    result.Name = "name here";
}
else
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The second option finds one element two times. Here

```
Repository
  .Query()
  .Any(ur => ur.CustomerId == customerId)
```

And here

```
Repository
  .Query()
  .Where(ur => ur.CustomerId == customerId)
  .Single()
```

And the first option finds just one time. It is a reason for choosing the first option. 
And also, you can make this code better:

```
var repo = Repository
  .Query()
  .Where(ur => ur.CustomerId == customerId)
  .SingleOrDefault();
```

Just write

```
var repo = Repository
  .Query()
  .SingleOrDefault(ur => ur.CustomerId == customerId);
```

And advice for future: use `Any()` when you want to check the *fact* that you has any element in query, but you *don't need* this element.

Answer (score 0):

in the second approach you are navigating  through items first by `Any` item to find a match, and again for getting match item. the `SingleOrDefault` wwill do the task in 1 step and checking one item (to determent if its null or not) is very cheaper than navigating all items.
so first approach is faster and better in my opinion.